# Rasterize a country with different colors

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have made a rectangle grid over a specific geographical region. Concretely, the grid contains a country's area.
Now in the grid, each cell has a certain color. I would like to visualize these colored cells but only with cells inside the country.
Basically, I'm trying to rasterize the country area.
The attached image shows my desire.
I'm trying to use mapbox for this purpose, but I cannot figure out how to implement it.
Could you please suggest a solution? 
Solutions with other map libraries are also welcomed.
Many thanks.[image]